# Backing up TFS manually because TFS/Sharepoint Integration is hosed

Tags: tfs, windows-server-2008, wss

After an ill-advised DCPROMO on our TFS server, and subsequent demotion, TFS continues to work but the SharePoint integration is totally hosed. SharePoint app pool refuses to run as a "Network Service" and so does SQLEXPRESS service. Unless there is some way to fix this, which I have not been able to find, I would like to totally re-install Windows Server 08 and TFS on our server. However, while trying to create a backup plan, I received an error relating to the fact that TFS cannot access MS SQL because of permissions issues. I would like to reliably and manually back up all TFS source control/history (I'm not worried about SP stuff at all, we haven't used it yet) and then restore it after I've re-installed stuff. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't really used ssrs/sharepoint etc you should be able to fairly easily detach any project collections and just migrate their databases to the new server. Each project collection only has one database normally named Tfs_{CollectionName}.  The move the database to the new server with TFS already installed on it, restore the databases and attach them in the management console.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138.aspx

Otherwise the recent versions of the TFS Server Power Tools have added a backup tab to the TFS management console which should be able to run you through making a backup.  http://blog.hinshelwood.com/creating-a-backup-in-team-foundation-server-2010-using-the-power-tools/

Comment: Manual export of SSRS reports http://blog.codeassassin.com/2010/07/22/export-all-report-definitions-for-a-team-project-collection/